# Is this the suitable scenario for Multi-column Indexes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, multiple-columns

My programming environment is Rails 2.3 and PostgreSQL 8 (shared Database on Heroku):
I have read this
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes#multicolumn_indexes
and other related resources on the Internet before I started building my app in the generic way:

My table has two columns A and B and are both indexed. (The rows are unique in terms of (A,B) pair)
But after I built my app, I found that I only query the table with two types of call:
myTable.find_by_A_and_B(a,b) and myTable.find_by_A(a)

We are expecting to have 10000+ entries in the table, the ratio of distinct A and distinct B is around 3:1.  We expect that for each unique value in A, there would be more than 1000+ rows that have different value in B; and for each unique value in B, there would be no more than 300 rows that have different value in A.

My question is: Whether the current database setup (with two separate indexes) can be classified as "efficient" in respect to the myTable.find_by_A_and_B(a,b) call (as I have no idea on the inner working of PostgreSQL).  And whether replacing the two indexes with just one multi-column indexes of (A,B) will provide significant speed up?

Thank you.

P.S.  In response to the comment, here is a bit more information:
According to this page, http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database
It is running PostgreSQL 8.3

And the follow is the migration schema for myTable:

```
create_table :myTable do |t|
    t.string :b
    t.integer:a
    t.boolean :c, :default => false
end

add_index :mytable, :b 
add_index :mytable, :a
```

Comment: It would make it easier for us if you provided the exact version number on postgres. There are big differences between 8.2 and 8.4. Also, like always, a table definition would help a lot. The answer depends on the data type of `a` and `b`. Finally, a glimpse on your actual query would make helping you easier.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - edited my answer in return.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of PostgreSQL [multi-column indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) can be used efficiently to filter on just one of the columns. This works best on the first column, but reasonably well for the others, too.

Also, 10.000 rows is a piece of cake for PostgreSQL. Tables with millions of rows are not uncommon.

Assuming we talk about btree indexes (default) on **integer** (int4) columns ...
... the **answer** is: just use **one multi-column index on `(a,b)`**.

Due to the [page layout](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/storage-page-layout.html) on disk (similar for tables and indexes), there is quite a bit of overhead per index row. Also, due to *data alignment* restrictions, one index `(a,b)` will use the exact same amount of disk space as an index on just `(a)` - on machines with `MAXALIGN` = 8 bytes (most 64-bit OS).
So, especially if you have lots of writes or limited disk space and/or RAM, your best bet is to just use one multi-column index on `(a,b)`. Maintaining indexes on heavily written tables carries quite a cost, too.

#### Edit in response to the update on the question:

- With `a` being `integer`, my answer is mostly valid. The index on `(a,b)` will be all or most of what you need.
- **Get rid of the separate index on `b`** as you obviously don't have queries on just `b`.
- As `b` is `text`, the multi-column index on (a,b) cannot profit from data-alignment as much as described above, but still. The greater the medium length of `b`, the more likely you will profit from an additional index on just `a`. With short `b` it probably doesn't pay. Else I would expect it to speed up `myTable.find_by_A(a)` by just a bit.
- This will likely be faster then two separate indexes on `a` and `b`, but not by a huge margin, as Postgres can combine two indexes in a `bitmap index scan`. This has improved since v.8.3.
- Be aware that btree indexes on `text` only help queries with '=' (more if you run on the `C` locale). Read the manual about [operator classes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/indexes-opclass.html).

You don't have to take my word, run some tests with [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-explain.html). It is very simple and informative and index creation for 10.000 rows is a matter of a second or so. Repeat each query a couple of times to populate the cache and get comparable results.